# Directly embedding JPEGs in an HTML file

Tags: internet-explorer, jpeg, mime, html

I can embed a mime encoded JPEG in an html page by saving the page from IE using the File-SaveAs menu and selecting (Web Archive, single file (*.mht)).

Renaming this .mht file with .eml enables Outlook to open it and send an HTML email.

My questions are:

1. How can I embed JPEG images directly in HTML pages (no external files).  Are the images just mime encoded inline in the HTML?
2. It appears that this is IE specific.  Do any other browsers support this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I embed JPEG images directly in HTML pages (no external files). Are the images just mime encoded inline in the HTML?

As other answerers point out, there is the concept of [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) but it is not supported by IE before 8, which renders it pretty useless.

Also, data URIs base64-encode the binary data, increasing the data volume by 33%.

As far as I know, sadly, there is no cross-browser way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

MHT files are not standard HTML.  The only way to do this in standard HTML is using [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: IE < 8 can't deal with data URIs.

Comment: IE8 has limited support, which does include images < 32 KiB.

Comment: Ok, so I now have a google search term 'data URIs'.  Do you have an example you can give?

Comment: 'MHT files are not standard HTML.'  Correct, this is why I say it appears to be IE specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `data:` URL I suppose (it's got a [public spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)) but for anything more than a few hundred bytes that would be truly evil.

Comment: That, plus IE < 8 can't deal with it.

Comment: @Pekka: So? Developing new things that support IE7 is a poor idea (easier to get the users to upgrade) and developing to support IE6 is a wicked and wrong-headed thing to do.

Comment: Also, data URIs are far more widely supported than MHT.

Comment: if you can afford to not support IE7, go ahead! I, for one, usually can't.